# Amazon attaching ebs volume time

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I would like to know the amount of time that I need to wait to attach and ebs of 200Gb to my instance. I expenting too much time in comparision with other times and smallers ebs. Does the size of the ebs affects in the time of attaching?

Thanks!

Post at [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=318427&#318427) informing of that problem.

I found something interesting, if I attach this volume to a large instance it gets attached in just a second, but if I use micro instance, it never ends... curious isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution for that problem, change the mount point to another one.

In my case I tried /dev/sdg with no succeed. After change it for /dev/sdh everything works.

I suppose that the reason why it works in large instance is that they use other mount point (/dev/sdf in the micro-instance this mount point is being used).

I hope this could help others ;)

Answer (score 1):

Once the EBS volume has been created, you can attach it to an instance immediately.

Instead of waiting a specific amount of time between attaching the volume to the instance and attempting to use the volume on the instance, I recommend simply waiting for the device to show up (e.g., /dev/xvdh or /dev/sdh).  This generally means that it's ready to use.

Comment: Yes, I think there is some kind of problem in my availability zone, because I attached the volume and after 8 hours is still attaching, and I can't find in /dev/sdg I posted a msg in the forum, and it has been reported to the service team.